# NestJS and TypeORM fail to connect my local Postgres database. Claims my database does not exist, even tho it does

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, nestjs, typeorm

I have NestJS application that uses TypeORM to connect to my local database. I create database with shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

SERVER="my_database_server";
PW="mysecretpassword";
DB="my_database";

echo "echo stop & remove old docker [$SERVER] and starting new fresh instance of [$SERVER]"
(docker kill $SERVER || :) && \
  (docker rm $SERVER || :) && \
  docker run --name $SERVER -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$PW \
  -e PGPASSWORD=$PW \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  -d postgres

# wait for pg to start
echo "sleep wait for pg-server [$SERVER] to start";
SLEEP 3;

# create the db 
echo "CREATE DATABASE $DB ENCODING 'UTF-8';" | docker exec -i $SERVER psql -U postgres
echo "\l" | docker exec -i $SERVER psql -U postgres
```

After that, it logs databases:
[image]

Then I fire up my application, and I encounter error "error: database "my_database" does not exist"

I use following code to connect to database:

```
static getDatabaseConnection(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        console.log(require('dotenv').config())
        return {
            type: 'postgres',
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 5432,
            username: 'postgres',
            password: 'mysecretpassword',
            database: 'my_database',
            entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
            synchronize: true,
        };
    }
```

Any ideas where do I go wrong?

Comment: I have my Ubuntu / Nestjs / TypeORM in a Vagrant box and I have Postgres setup on my Mac host.  I use this address:  "host": "10.0.2.2".  That may work for you.

Comment: Any Leads on this, i'm stuck too.

Answer (score 4):

When connecting to a docker instance, you should usually use the service name. In this case I guess it is `my_database_server` as `host` parameter.

```
return {
            type: 'postgres',
            host: "my_database_server",
            port: 5432,
            username: 'postgres',
            password: 'mysecretpassword',
            database: 'my_database',
            entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
            synchronize: true,
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

1. "localhost" isn't address of your docker container. Which address uses docker you can look running command:

   $ docker inspect {your_container_name}

for me is: 172.17.0.2

[image]

2. Try enable SSL, adding next configuration lines:

> ssl: true,
> extra: { ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false } }

Answer (score 0):

Try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`